# Jquery open questionpart and close other questionpart

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle

I have the following code:

```
<div class="faq">
<h1 class="question">Question</h1>
<p class="answer">Answer</p>
</div>

<div class="faq">
<h1 class="question"> Question </h1>
<p class="answer">Answer</p>
</div>

<div class="faq">
<h1 class="question"> Question </h1>
<p class="answer">Answer</p>
</div>
```

And I like to click on the h1 to expand the answer. the `<p>` tag is set to display:none, but it's the jquery which is bugging me. Exact requirements:

- On click of an h1, the corresponding answer should open
- On click of another h1, other question answers should close, and the corresponding answer should open
- On click of an h1 while that answer is open, the answer should close.

I've tried the following:

```
jQuery(".faq > h1").click(function () { 
jQuery(this).siblings().hide();
jQuery(this).closest(".question").children("p").toggle("slow");

});

});
```

Almost does the trick, but on click of the currently open question, it closes and re-opens which looks verry buggy.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you should take a look at jQuery UI accordion. It will to the job for you. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(".faq > h1").on('click',
function() {
    var $sib = jQuery(' + .answer', this);
    jQuery('.answer:visible').not($sib).hide('fast');
    if($sib.is(':visible')) $sib.hide('slow'); else $sib.show('slow');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oqolit/3/edit)

Comment: Both answers do the same as my first solution, however it still closes and then re-opens the clicked answer. In this situation I would like to close the answer if it's already open.

Should this be done with a css property condition?

Comment: Thanks, but that does not do the trick. It actually does not do anything, maybe a script error?

Comment: @DaanTwice check out the demo, pls.

Comment: I see, it works like a charm. It did not work on my site due to the wordpress head, placing the library after the wp_head fixed this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (hide all "answer" class elements and then show only currently selected one)

```
jQuery(".faq > h1").click(function () { 
    jQuery('.answer').hide();
    jQuery(this).next('.answer').show("slow");
});
```